# How can I fix my c code for my school project

Tags: c

I'm doing some Chinese zodiac assignment for my programming course in C, and I'm not sure if there's a way I can write this doe in much less lines:

```
int main() {

int year;

printf("Enter your year of birth: \n");
scanf_s("%i", &year);

if (year % 12 == 0) {
    return 0;
} else if (year % 12 == 1) {
    return 1;
} else if (year % 12 == 2) {
    return 2;
} else if (year % 12 == 3) {
    return 3;
} else if (year % 12 == 4) {
    return 4;
} else if (year % 12 == 5) {
    return 5;
} else if (year % 12 == 6) {
    return 6;
} else if (year % 12 == 7) {
    return 7;
} else if (year % 12 == 8) {
    return 8;
} else if (year % 12 == 9) {
    return 9;
} else if (year % 12 == 10) {
        return 10;               
} else if (year % 12 == 11) {
    return 11;
}
```

I want to know if there's any way to optimize this code.

Comment: Uh … `return year % 12;`? Also, note that `year % 12` will *never* be 12. By definition it takes on values in the range [0, 11].

Comment: @KonradRudolph Right, I fixed it, thanks for letting me know about that mistake.

Comment: Do you really want your main() function to return the value? By convention main() returns 0 for program success and a non-zero value if something goes wrong.

Comment: Did you maybe want to *print* the result instead of *return*ing it?

Comment: Note, if you cannot write a chain of `if-else` like that with a final `else` then you have missed something in the logic or a sensible precaution.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "By definition it takes on values in the range [0, 11]." is amiss. `int % 12`  takes on values in the range [-11, 11].

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten the function like in the following code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int zodiac(void)
{
    int year;

    printf("Enter your year of birth: \n");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    if ((year % 12) == 0)
    {
        return 12;
    }
    else
    {
        return (year % 12);
    }
}

int main()
{

    printf("Your zodiac year is: %d\n", zodiac());
    return 0;
}
```

Testing that out gives the following terminal output.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Zodiac/bin/Release$ ./Zodiac 
Enter your year of birth: 
1955
Your zodiac year is: 11
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

`year % 12` reduces the year to the range [-11 ... 11].  Use that as a starting point to get the numbers [0...11].

```
int chinese_zodiac = year % 12;
if (chinese_zodiac < 0) {
  chinese_zodiac += 12;
}
printf("Chinese zodiac index %d\n", chinese_zodiac);
printf("Chinese zodiac number %d\n", chinese_zodiac + 1);
static const char *animal[12] = { "Rat", "Ox", "Tiger", /* rest for OP to add */ };
printf("Chinese zodiac animal %s\n", animal[chinese_zodiac]);
```

Ref: [Chinese zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac#Signs)

Note: Feb 01 2022 – Jan 21 2023 is the year of the [tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_(zodiac)#2022%E2%80%932023) (year number 3).  OP's `year` may need an offset.